# Error setting cookies in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

On my website, I am working on a system that instead of typing in a password, you will be allowed access by injecting a certain cookie into the browser for a certain period of time (good for monthly payments, etc).

But when I set a cookie to the user from *http://mc.magicalts.tk/COOKIE-LINK* to be used on *http://mc.magicalts.tk/premium.php*, it doesn't show up in my cookies list. Here is my code:

```
<?php
setcookie("the-product-key-here", 1, time()+2592000, '/premium.php','http://mc.magicalts.tk/', 0);
?>
<h1>Now go to mc.magicalts.tk/premium.php</h1>
<i>Support on Skype: iExplosive // Alts</i>
```

And here is the one from premium.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_COOKIE['GENTOKEN-9U8L7JREKO'])){
$lines = file('http://pastebin.com/raw/wu7gHcZF');
echo $lines[array_rand($lines)];
} else {
    if(isset($_COOKIE['MGK-JNV-LDI-ALTS'])){
        $lines = file('http://pastebin.com/raw/wu7gHcZF');
        echo $lines[array_rand($lines)];
    } else {
        echo "<b>Hold up there! Please wait 30 minutes before generating a new alt.</b><br><b>While you wait, visit <i>forums.magicalts.tk</i></b>"; 
    }
           if(isset($_COOKIE['MGK-XIQ-XXN-ALT'])){
        $lines = file('http://pastebin.com/raw/wu7gHcZF');
        echo $lines[array_rand($lines)];
    } else {
        echo "<b>Hold up there! Please wait 30 minutes before generating a new alt.</b><br><b>While you wait, visit <i>forums.magicalts.tk</i></b>"; 
    }
}

?>
```

The code above has multiple cookies because it is used for all the product keys.
Please site your sources (if any) to help me better understand your answer. Thank you very much :D

Comment: Is `premium.php`in your root directory? example: `http://domain.com/premium.php` ?

Comment: "Please site your sources (if any) to help me better understand your answer." i'm writing a full bibliography.

Comment: premium.php is not in my root directory